# How to disable IE11 WebBrowser control scaling

Tags: javascript, c#, css, .net, internet-explorer

I have spent 2 days trying to solve this problem, and finally, I ask you, dear StackoverFlowers.
I am developing an application for 27' multi-touch screens on C# 4.5 and I need a WebBrowser element within it. A user should only be able to pan the page by Y-axis and click on items.
I disabled text selection, items dragging using JS; navigation using C#; but can't make it not scalable.

I installed IE11 and turned it on using registry key (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION).

My HTML-file contains:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

My CSS-file contains:

```
*
{
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -ms-content-zooming: none;
    touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

But when I pinch with two fingers to zoom it still zooms. 
Can't get rid of this annoying function.

How to disable it using any of JS, jQuery, IE11, .NET, Windows instruments?

P.S. I am using Windows 8 and there is no "disable multi-touch gestures" in Mouse settings of control panel like in Windows 7 :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different approaches didn't give any appropriate results.

The solution was the following: uninstall Windows 8, install Windows 7 and disable multi-touch gestures.

Answer (score 0):

try with ;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width; user-scalable=no; 
initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0">
```